# Realtime config update based on CRON for AWS EC2

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have this in my user data in the launch configuration for the EC2 for a realtime config update:

```
# Update TFE config
cat > update-config.sh << 'EOF'
aws s3 sync s3://${s3_bucket} /etc/tfe-config
replicatedctl app-config export > /etc/tf-config/tfe-settings.json
aws s3 sync /etc/tfe-config s3://${s3_bucket}
EOF
chmod +x update-config.sh

# Schedule tasks
cat > ~/mycron << 'EOF'
* * * * * /etc/tfe-config/update-config.sh
EOF
crontab ~/mycron
rm ~/mycron
```

Is this a suitable approach for a config update in realtime or are there any problems since I execute 2 times `aws s3 sync` withing the same cron job?

Comment: Why not just echo the commands and redirect them to update-config.sh and ~/mycron respectively as opposed to using a heredoc?

Comment: What is the benefit of your suggestion?

Comment: You are using redirection one way as opposed to two